# OO-question re: interfaces and is-a vs. has-a

Tags: c#, interfaces

Disclaimer: the following is written without further distinction in the object oriented terminology as C# is implementing it: classes, interfaces and instances, etc.

Let's assume the following scenario: there are different classes `Apple`, `Avocado` and `Egg` with no shared inheritance hierarchy except for `Object` at the top. All those classes implement the interface `IPeelable` which obviously makes sense for all three. Each of the `IPeelable` implementations of course is using methods specific to their respective class.

The class `MushyPulp` wants to build on top of `IPeelable` classes but needs to bring its own member variables like `float Volume`. `MushyPulp` can e.g. increase in volume if you first `peel` a little more and then `squeeze` a little more, where `squeeze` is introduced only in `MushyPulp` and independent of the exact substance that is squeezed.
A `MushyPulp` instance in my eyes in essence **is a** `IPeelable` object. My problem: I somehow don't understand how to define this relationship in C#. The only way I could make it work is to have a private `IPeelable` instance in `MushyPulp` and reroute all `IPeelable` methods of `MushyPulp` through to this object - the code of course is a entirely boiler-plate indirection.

From a technical perspective it looks like what I want would be multiple inheritance in disguise - is there a way to have that, restricted to interfaces (somehow) in C#?

**EDIT:**
My creative translation of my actual programming problem towards a food based example didn't work out so well. I rephrase my question a bit towards more technical terms:

I have a range of otherwise completely unrelated producer classes which can put out `byte`s sequentially (they implement the interface `IPeelable`). And I want to have a more complex "something" that can put out `byte`s sequentially but also emit whole datagrams, costructed from a sequence of those `byte`s, depending on the type of data I am asking from it. So either a spoon- cup- or plateful of mushy pulp (`byte`s interpreted and transformed, e.g. type cast to a `float`) or a `byte` of peeled substance. The source of the substance is understandably anonymous beyond the `IPeelable` interface. The question is, what is the "something"? A class with a member of an `IPeelable` capable class as for now, but is that the final word on OO here?

Comment: I find it hard to follow what MushyPulp is supposed to here - is there supposed to be some real world relationship that I'm supposed to already understand to get your question? What do you want when you say "MushyPulp wants to build on top of IPeelable classes"? Can you peel a MushyPulp? Is an Apple a MushyPulp? Do you get a MushyPulp by peel()ing an Apple?

Comment: "A `MushyPulp` instance in my eyes in essence is a `IPeelable`" This means that `MushyPulp` should implement `IPeelable` doesn't it? What is the issue?

Comment: @JeremyHunt I tried to clarify a bit.

Comment: @Goyo that the implementation of `IPeelable` in `MushyPulp` looks like entirely dispensable repetition, more or less like `public void peel(float x) { _peelable.peel(x); }`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting it. What does peeling a Peelable by x do? What does squeezing do? What do we hope to achieve by squeezing a Pulp instead of squeezing an Apple (and maybe in the process adding volume to a Pulp?)

Comment: @JeremyHunt Ok, maybe this way: I have a producer which puts out bytes sequentially (`IPeelable`). And I have a "something" that can put out bytes sequentially but also emit whole datagrams, costructed from a sequence of those bytes, depending on what I am asking it. So either a spoon- cup- or plateful of mushy pulp or a bit of peeled substance. The source of the substance is understandably anonymous beyond the `IPeelable`. The question is, what is the "something"? A class with a member of an `IPeelable` as for now, but is that the final word on OO here?

Comment: Whether it is dispensable or not is your call but "[a] `MushyPulp` instance in my eyes in essence is a `IPeelable`" sounds like it is not (in your eyes anyway). Delegation is more boilerplate than repetition. Whether delegation is appropiate here or not I don't think we can tell from your description.

Comment: @Goyo I edited  my question towards a better ...er.. understandability

Comment: @Vroomfondel Please dont transform your real problem into fruits, that just creates an XY problem. From your edit: You have producers that put out bytes. Lets call them `IBytesProducer` with a function `ByteSequence produceBytes()`. Then you have "something" that takes the bytes and constructs, for example, a datagram. Sounds to me like "something" is a simple function `Datagram createDatagramFromBytes(ByteSequence)` which is called like this `createDatagramFromBytes(producer.produceBytes())`. So the answer to _what is "something"?_ is _a simple function_.

Comment: I would make the same comment after your edit. You more or less confirmed that you want that "something" to implement `IPeelable`. Then you ask whether it sould delegate to another `IPeelable` object but the answer to that depends on details that we don't know.

Comment: Just a minor point of nomenclature: we normally say that object is at the top of the hierarchy, not the bottom. Object is a supertype; derived types are subtypes, so we have the intuition that the "super" should be above the "sub". And in type lattice theory object is the "top type". (Though if you include pointer types, object is only the top type of the managed types.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A `MushyPulp` instance in my eyes in essence is a `IPeelable` object. My problem: I somehow don't understand how to define this relationship in C#. The only way I could make it work is to have a private `IPeelable` instance in `MushyPulp` and reroute all `IPeelable` methods of `MushyPulp` through to this object - the code of course is a entirely boiler-plate indirection.

What you are describing is the delegation pattern: type A delegates the handling of functionality to a private instance of type B. And you are correct that C# doesn't directly support the delegation pattern and instead requires you to write boilerplate code along the lines of:

```
public void peel(float x) => _peelable.peel(x);
```

There are tools, such as ReSharper, [that support generating that boilerplate code for you](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html), but you still end up with that boilerplate code.

Another option is to expose `_peelable` via a property in `MushyPulp`:

```
public IPeelable PulpProvidingObject { get => _peelable; }
```

though you then risk running into conflicts with the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Another alternative is to rethink those "is a " and "has a" relationships. A peelable item *has a* mushy pulp. So maybe your solution should be to have the `IPeelable` interface provide access to the `MushyPulp` instance that results from peeling and squeezing it.

Comment: I added an edit to my question. May I kindly ask you to see if that changes your answer (a bit)?

Comment: Newer versions of Visual Studio will also write that boilerplate for you. There's now an "implement interface delegating from member" option when you have an unimplemented interface, which I was pleasantly surprised to see.

Comment: @EricLippert I think what I am was really asking for was something like C#'s extension methods, but for data, i.e. the additive extension of a type with new member variables, where the type is identified just by an interface. Is this an ill-posed request due to some principal contradiction/impossibility in the type system?

Comment: @Vroomfondel: No, it is a perfectly sensible feature request for the language and frankly, I was surprised when I discovered that it was not in v1.0. This pattern is common in COM -- the easiest way to implement it is via tear-off interfaces -- and I figured that a new language that was designed to be a better C++ with a better COM would have it as a language feature. Adding it was never a priority for the design team either.

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for that tip. I didn't know that feature existed.

Comment: @Vroomfondel, if it's of interest to you, there are issues on the C# language GitHub repo requesting this feature, eg [Proposal: Allow auto implementing delegated interface](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/234). But as Eric says, there seems to be little interest amongst the language team to provide support for the pattern in C#.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I have been programming OO only for a few weeks and already smashing my forehead against the glass roof ;). Are there other OO languages which somehow circumvent this restriction, or even implement it directly? C++ can somehow do that via multiple inheritance, no?

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled using only interfaces, only abstract classes, or a combination of both interfaces and abstract classes. The two are not mutually exclusive. Which approach you use depends greatly on both how these classes will be used as well as personal preference (or company standards).

In addition, interfaces can inherit from other interfaces. Here is an example of using both:

```
    public interface IPeelable
    {
        bool IsTropical { get; set; }
        string PreferredTool { get; set; }
        void Peel();
    }
    public interface IMushyPulp : IPeelable
    {
        double Volume { get; set; }
        void Squeeze();
    }

    public abstract class Peelable : IPeelable
    {
        public bool IsTropical { get; set; }
        public string PreferredTool { get; set; }
        public abstract void Peel();
    }

    public class Apple : Peelable
    {
        public override void Peel() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public abstract class MushyPulp : Peelable, IMushyPulp
    {
        public double Volume { get; set; }
        public abstract void Squeeze();
    }

    public class Orange : MushyPulp
    {
        public override void Peel() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override void Squeeze() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

*Note: In this example IMushyPulp inherits from IPeelable - but that isn't necessary for this example to work. It can, however, make using the IMushyPulp interface easier to use elsewhere.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could have an interface and an abstract class

```
public interface IPeelable
{
    void A();
    void B();
}

public sealed class MushyPulp : IPeelable
{
    // Custom versions
    void IPeelable.A() {
    }

    // Custom versions
    void IPeelable.B() {
    }
}
```

You can look at your objects as IPeelable and when you call A or B methods the mushie ones will have the custom version of those methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the real issue here is a single responsibility problem. You have two distinct concepts, one represents a type of pulp and the other how it is delivered. So what you really want - if I understand correctly - is an instance method on your `Peelable` that is something like this:

```
void Peel(PulpDeliverer deliverer)
{
    deliverer.AddPulp(this.Pulp);
}
```

Where `PulpDeliverer` might be `Spoon` or `Plate` or whatever.

Whether this method lives on an abstract base class for your `Peelable` or whether you even need inheritance (maybe a single `Peelable` class with injected strategies and factory methods for each type of fruit?) is a separate issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this. `IPeelable` is a C# interface and thus can never have a base class. I think I  goofed up with the translation to food examples. Did you read my edit?

Comment: @Vroomfondel I'm using `Peelable` as representing any implementation of `IPeelable`, or an abstract base class for `IPeelable` implementations, or as a concrete replacement (or single implementation) for `IPeelable` as a single class with injected strategies instead of having distinct classes per type of fruit - as you see fit. The detail of that is not really important. The point is for the `IPeelable` implementation to invoke the deliverer instead of trying to implement the deliverer as a wrapper or decorator for `IPeelable`, which is fundamentally the wrong model imo.

Comment: But what you propose will mean that `Peelable` et al will need to use `PulpDeliverer` which to me looks like an inversion in the hierarchy - the interface provider must know about the interface user or the interface mediator - or do I get you wrong again?